# Android Volley MalformedURLException after handling custom URL

Tags: android, android-volley

My app is receiving a custom URL that looks like this: myapp://login/token12345.

I handle that in my main activity's onCreate (ie. getIntent().getData()), parse out the token, and then make an API request using Volley with a URL like this https://staging.redacted.com/a?confirm=token12345

However, I get a strange MalformedURLException:

```
NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL https://staging.redacted.com/a?confirm=token12345
java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad URL https://staging.redacted.com/a?confirm=token12345
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
        at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
 Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: myapp
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:182)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:137)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.processResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:451)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:300)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

It appears to be using a valid URL, but it then says the scheme is invalid (myapp://). It's like the custom URL that I received is somehow getting into my subsequent volley request. Does someone know what is happening here?

Also of note - when I debug the app and put a break just prior to sending the volley request, magically the volley request then works.

Comment: The address `https://staging.redacted.com/a?confirm=token12345` not available (I cannot access from web browsers in my PC)

Comment: Yeah, that's on purpose (I don't want to post my server URL). Its not a malformed URL though.

Comment: Ok, post your request so that I can check, of course with a sample URL :)

Comment: This "magically" stopped happening with no code changes (maybe just a clean build?)

Comment: I cannot be sure without your code :)

Comment: The problem was a redirect on the server side. So this wasn't a volley issue at all.